# Error when using Alternate Key in CDS connector

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, common-data-service, xrmtoolbox

I'm using the *Common Data Service for Apps* connector in Azure Data Factory to load data into Dynamics 365

I've done this successfully before using the entity key. See this question: [Loading records into Dynamics 365 through ADF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054515/loading-records-into-dynamics-365-through-adf)

Now I'm trying to use an alternate key to Upsert records into the `account` entity. (In this case insert)

#### In Dynamics

I've created two custom attributes fields in `account`:

```
Field name        Data Type    Field Type    Max Length
=======================================================
xyz_srcsystem     Single Line  Simple        50
xyz_srccode       Single Line  Simple        50
```

Then I created a Key on `account` which contains these fields:

`xyz_alternatekeyaccount`

#### In ADF

Then I used a *Copy Data* activity in ADF to copy data from a SQL view into the account entity, using the CDS connector as a target.

This my source SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
CAST(NULL as uniqueidentifier) as accountid,
'ADFTest1' as accountnumber, 'ADF Test 1' as [description],  
'nmcdermaid@xyz.com.au' as emailaddress1,
CAST('TST' AS NVARCHAR(50)) as xyz_srcsystem,
CAST('1' AS NVARCHAR(50)) as xyz_srccode
```

In the target, in the *Alternate key name* field I entered the alternate key name: `xyz_alternatekeyaccount`

The error I get when I run the pipeline is

> Invalid type for entity id value

Some test to rule out edge cases:

- if I put a dummy alternate key in, I get *Cannot retrieve key information of alternate key 'xyz_alternatekeyaccountx' for entity 'account'*. This implies it is finding the alternate key correctly
- If I remove the alternate key from the connector, it drops back to the other usual set of errors that I see
- When I pull the entity into SQL using the CDM connector, the custom attributes arrive as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`
- I've tried casting to these data types: `NVARCHAR(MAX)` `NVARCHAR(50)` `VARCHAR(MAX)` `VARCHAR(50)`
- If I use the normal key (not an alternate key), and get the datatype wrong (anything other than GUID), I'll get the same error

Also see this Doco GitHub I raised:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59028

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed the source SQL to this, it worked:

```
SELECT 
'ADFTest1' as accountnumber, 'ADF Test 1' as [description],  
'nmcdermaid@xyz.com.au' as emailaddress1,
CAST('TST' AS NVARCHAR(50)) as xyz_srcsystem,
CAST('1' AS NVARCHAR(50)) as xyz_srccode
```

Note: the difference is I did not include the true primary key in the source dataset.

Not that if you want to UPSERT a new record (INSERT) and this isn't based on an alternate key, you have to include a NULL primary key